# Calculating the elapsed time of Oracle Database Startup operation

Tags: oracle, startup, time

I'm trying to calculate the elapsed time of Oracle Database `startup` command. The view `V$INSTANCE` contains the `STARTUP_TIME` column which tells at what time the database is started. But, i need way to find the time elapsed from the time we enter `startup` till the database is opened.

Since, we can't query `SYSDATE` or `SYSTIMESTAMP` when the database is not open, im finding it difficult to come up with a logic.

Is there any other way we can get the elapsed time for `startup` operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ time sqlplus -s / as sysdba<<EOF
> startup
> exit
> EOF
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  536867640 bytes
Fixed Size                  8659768 bytes
Variable Size             322961408 bytes
Database Buffers          197132288 bytes
Redo Buffers                8114176 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.

real    0m14.578s
user    0m0.014s
sys     0m0.016s
[oracle@o71 ~]$
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. This helped me.

Comment: In addition to response of @Balazs Papp, you can just look at the alert log. find the timestamp associated with the message "Starting ORACLE instance", then find the timestamp associated with the message "Completed: alter database open"